# Web components are not loading after upgrading Angular from 7 to 8

Tags: angular, web-component

I upgraded my angular app from version 7 to 8. I am using a custom web component in the application which is broken now.

I am getting the following error in the browser dev tool:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'HTMLElement': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.
at new e (webcomponents.core.js:5)
at HTMLDocument.createElement (<anonymous>)
at EmulatedEncapsulationDomRenderer2.createElement (platform-browser.js:2791)
at EmulatedEncapsulationDomRenderer2.createElement (platform-browser.js:3036)
at AnimationRenderer.createElement (animations.js:473)
at DebugRenderer2.createElement (core.js:45747)
at createElement (core.js:42861)
at createViewNodes (core.js:44165)
at createEmbeddedView (core.js:44068)
at callWithDebugContext (core.js:45631)
```

I am not sure how to fix this.

Is this because Angular upgrade deleted some polyfills which is required to load web components (which is not supported by the browser yet)? I'm using latest version of Chrome - 76

Would appreciate any help on this!

Comment: add adapter https://unpkg.com/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs@2.2.10/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js

Comment: But my question is how it was working with Angular 7 and why it's broken after the upgrade? I am sure it's missing some web component polyfills. But I want to understand the cause before I add it back.

Comment: It is transpiling issue. If you are transpiling or using ES5 then you need to bundle native-shim for browsers with native Web components support.ES5-style classes don't work with native Custom Elements

Comment: Angular upgrade changed "module": "es2015" to "module": "esnext" in tsconfig. Apart from that I don't see any other change in tsconfig. I am still not convinced how it was transpiling with Angular 7 and not with 8

Comment: @Ansuman Did you ever figure out the issue? I am having same problem

Answer (score 0):

Update document-register-element package also.

```
npm i document-register-element
```

Comment: And why did not Angular upgrade take care of this? Even it's not mentioned in 'https://update.angular.io'. Now I am not sure if anything else is broken as well unless I test each and every functionality.

Answer (score 0):

according to **jessndaa**

> https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24556#issuecomment-398920529

changing to "target":"es5" in the `tsconfig.json` to "target":"es2015"
these is my `tsconfig.json` file

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}`
```

Comment: remove node_module and instal again npm i

Comment: Still the same after removing node_modules folder and installing the packages again